# Equivalent of keyboard shortcut "F12" in xaml files

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working at some WPF applications, written in C#, based on XAML files, programmed according to the MVVM way of working.

While programming, nothing easier than the <kbd>F12</kbd> button to know where your information is defined, as you can see from the following random piece of source code:

file "ClientMaterialService.cs":

```
if (OP.Direction == 1) { UIOP.In = true; UIOP.Out = false; }
```

Cursor on `OP`, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, result : file "ClientMaterialService.cs", line `Unit PO = ...;`
Cursor on `Direction`, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, result : file "Unit.cs", line `public byte Direction { get; set; }`
Like this, there are plenty of examples.

But it's not like that in a XAML file, as you can see here:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cmb_MPNr"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Unit.MPNr, Mode=TwoWay}" ...
```

Cursor on `ComboBox`, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, result : file "...\ComboBox.cs" (decompiled), line ... => OK
Cursor on `Unit`, press <kbd>F12</kbd>, result : file "Binding.cs" (decompiled), line `public PropertyPath Path`
(that's the general definition of a binding!!!)

That's not what I want! I want to know where this particular `Unit` is defined. (In my application, the previous developers had the bad habit of using the same name for classes and objects, and as there are plenty of objects, called `Unit`, I would like to be sure which one I'm dealing with. I hoped that <kbd>F12</kbd> could show me that but it's not the case.

Does anybody know a simple workaround? (Please, don't ask me to rename all the objects, that's a Sisyphus labour :-) )

Comment: "While programming, nothing easier than the F12 button to know where your information is defined" - there are certainly easier ways. for example in my project views have design-time DataContext and I don't even need to click F12 to know where bound properties are defined

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody know a simple workaround?

Unlike a member in C#, `Unit` is just a string that *eventually* gets evaluated at looked up at *runtime* using reflection. The compiler doesn't know whether the property exists or where it is defined.

So there is no "workaround" available in Visual Studio. If you know the `DataContext` of the element - which you should - you can easily search for the property in this type.